# Populating HTML Table with Data from mysql Gives Empty Table Cells

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to populate a table with data from a MySQL database with PHP,
but the table cells remain empty when the code is executed, and I don't receive any errors

Below is the code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = ""; // Mysql username 
$password = ""; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "test_mysql"; // Table name 
$server_name = "localhost";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if($con->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
}

// Check connection
if($con->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result = $con->query($sql);
?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                            <td><? echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
                            <td><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
                            <td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
$con->close();
?>
```

I think it could be missing a code, I appreciate any help you can give me!

Comment: Aside from the typo pointed out below is `$result->num_rows` greater than zero? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = ""; // Mysql username 
$password = ""; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "test_mysql"; // Table name 
$server_name = "localhost";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if($con->connect_error){
   die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
}

// Check connection
if($con->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result = $con->query($sql);
?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                // output data of each row
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
                        <td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: You used `row` in `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` instead of `while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())`

Answer (score 1):

You have used `$row` Instead of `$rows` in while loop declaration.

```
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo"<tr>
           <td>{$rows['name']}</td>
           <td>{$rows['lastname']}</td>
           <td>{$rows['email']}</td>
           <td align='center'><a href='update.php?id={$rows['id']}'>update</a></td>
         </tr>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution would be for you to add below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result = $con->query($sql);
```

**var_dump($result);die;** //Include this line of code and see if it is actually getting what you selected from the database. If you can get those records inside the var_dump(), then you can tell what next to do

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is different variable names

Here is variable `$row`:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

Here is variable `$rows`:

```
<td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
```

I would expect that to atleast give an warning somewhere though

Answer (score 0):

you use `$rows` instead of `$row` this is you correct code:

```
<tr>
    <td><? echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<? echo $row['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Tried the corrections but it still gives empty table cells